# Prolog - extract edges from an adjacency matrix

Tags: list, prolog, graph-theory

I have a list of lists which represents an adjacency matrix of a graph.
Im looking for a way to extract the graphs edges from it:

```
?- getEdges([[0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0]],Edges).
Edges = [[1,2],[2,4],[2,3]]
```

thx

Comment: What vertex does `[1,2]` stand for? Maybe you meant edges?

Comment: you are right, corrected that

Comment: Have you made any attempts? Exactly where are you stuck? Judging from your sample result, this is an undirected graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution (assuming a directed graph) would be somewhat like the following:

Suppose that you are examining the adjacency matrix and you are at a certain row. You would need a predicate that examines this row's adjacency list and filters out all `0`-elements, producing a list with elements of the form:

```
(From, To)
```

where `From` corresponds to the row index and `To` corresponds to the non-zero columns.
A simple predicate that does this would be called like

```
?- rowEdges(Row, AdjList, Result).
```

So you can try to do this:

```
rowEdges(Row, AdjList, Result) :- edges(AdjList, 1, Row, [], Result).

edges([H|T], Column, Row, Acc, Res) :-
    NewColumn is Column + 1,
    ( H =:= 1 -> edges(T, NewColumn, Row, [(Row, Column)|Acc], Res);
      edges(T, NewColumn, Row, Acc, Res)).
edges([], _, _, Res, Res).
```

The predicate `edges/5` examines each element of the row's adjacency list, while tracking the column index of the element. If an edge should be added, it would be in the form `(Row, Column)` which is why we have to provide `Row` as an argument.

`rowEdges/3` simply provides the right initialization, which should be an empty list for the accumulator (`Acc`), and `1` for the column index.
Now you can just take `rowEdges/3` and apply it to every row you have to find all edges via a similar process.

Example:

```
?- rowEdges(2, [1,0,1,1,0,1], Result).
Result = [(2, 6), (2, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1)].
```

If you would like your edges to be produced in ascending column order, you would simply modify `rowEdges/3` to produce reversed output, since `edges/5` is using an accumulator.

```
rowEdges(Row, AdjList, Result) :- edges(AdjList, 1, Row, Acc, Res), reverse(Res, Result).
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to, first, create a predicate which identifies a valid edge. Here's a simple predicate to do so, for undirected graphs:

```
edge(M, [R,C]) :-
    nth1(R, M, Row),
    nth1(C, Row, 1),
    R =< C.               % Remove this for directed graphs
```

Here's a sample query:

```
| ?- edge([[0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0]],Edge).

Edge = [1,2] ? a

Edge = [2,3]

Edge = [2,4]

(1 ms) no
| ?-
```

It identifies each edge with each backtrack. It makes use of the `nth1/3` predicate, which is the relation `nth1(N, List, Element)` that says, *`Element` is at location `N` in `List`*, where the first element is element number `1`.

For directed graphs, just remove the `R =< C` condition, then you'll get:

```
| ?- edge([[0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0]],Edge).

Edge = [1,2] ? a

Edge = [2,1]

Edge = [2,3]

Edge = [2,4]

Edge = [3,2]

Edge = [4,2]

(1 ms) no
| ?-
```

If you want another way to represent an edge rather than a 2-element list `[R,C]`, you need only change the head of the clause from `edge(M, [R,C])` to, for example, `edge(M, R-C)`:

```
| ?- edge([[0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0]],Edge).

Edge = 1-2 ? a

Edge = 2-3

Edge = 2-4

(1 ms) no
| ?-
```

If you want to collect all of the edges into a single list, you can use `setof/3`:

```
all_edges(M, Edges) :-
    setof(E, edge(M, E), Edges).

| ?- all_edges([[0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0]],E), Edges).

Edges = [1-2,2-3,2-4]

yes
| ?-
```